# Enable/disable button depending on whether an input in a text box is in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nearly finished writing this code: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jkk9/11/

but I can't figure out how to search the select box for the value in my text box and enable/disabled the button accordingly.

That's probably enough explanation.. the code explains all...

Thank you :).

**EDIT** Here's my original code from jsfiddle:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>apple</option>
    <option>banana</option>
    <option>pear</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input id="filter" type="text"/>
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter').keyup(function() {
         // if select box contains input then
         //   $('#mybtn').attr(disabled, 'disabled');
         //}
         //else {
         //   $('#mybtn').removeAttr('disabled');
         //}
    });
});
```

Comment: You should include your code in the question so that in the future it is still useful if jsfiddle doesn't exist.

Comment: please provide source code as well. the fiddle is great but it is better to have source code right there, not only on an external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want by filtering the options for ones matching the text and checking the length:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ($('#myselect option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === text;
    }).length) {
        $('#mybtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#mybtn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/2Jkk9/16/

Comment: Nearly... I just changed === 0 to !== 0 because I wanted it the other way round:http://jsfiddle.net/2Jkk9/15/

Comment: @omnosis I assumed that 'select contains' means that one of the options is equal

Comment: @richard i think contains mean contains a text and maybe some other text. so if the `apple` is selected, the `aapple` is also good because this __contains__ the `apple`.

Comment: I guess @alemaster will have to clarify that :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `each()` to loop through to traverse your list and get value by `.val()`

check modified code.

```
(function() {
        $('#filter').keyup(function() {
            $('#myselect option').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == $('#filter').val())
            {
                $('#mybtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
alert('hello');

            }
                else
                {
                     $('#mybtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                }


            });
             // if select box contains input then
             //   $('#mybtn').attr(disabled, 'disabled');
             //}
             //else {
             //   $('#mybtn').removeAttr('disabled');
             //}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#filter').keyup(function() {
        if($("#filter").val().split($("#myselect").val()).length > 1) {
            $('#mybtn').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#mybtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

this works if the filter **contains** the selected value, not only when the same.

Answer (score -2):

What about:
give your options a value like:

```
<select>
  <option value="1"></option>
</select>

    $('#myselect').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            //do this
        } else { 
        //do this
        }

    });
```

Comment: How does that help answer the question?

Comment: ... I have to learn to read.... second time this happend >.>
Sorry didnt see the textbox part. already wondered why he used keyup.
Excuses...